# Proof Vandermonde's identity using generating function

Tags: generating-functions

> Proof Vandermonde's identity using generating function
>   $$\binom{m+n}{r}=\sum_{k=0}^r\binom{m}{r-k}\binom{n}{k}$$

$\binom{m+n}{r}$ is the coefficient of $x^r$ in $(1+x)^{m+n}$. Then I try,
\begin{align}
(1+x)^{m+n}&=(1+x)^m(1+x)^n\\
[x^r]\left(\sum_{k=0}^{m+n}\binom{m+n}{k}x^k\right)&=[x^r]\left(\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{m}{k}x^k\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^k\right)
\end{align}
Now I lost. How to establish the identity$?$ any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have lost all the binomial coefficients in your last formula.

Comment: I just want to compare the coefficient of $x^r$ on both side. Isn't it work$?$ @ancientmathematician

Answer (score 3):

I add yet another answer, even though Rob's answer is definitive, hoping to make things even clearer. As we saw, from
$$
(1+x)^{m+n}=(1+x)^m(1+x)^n$$
we infer that
$$
\sum_{r=0}^\infty \binom{n+m}{r}x^r=\sum_{\rho=0}^\infty \sum_{\sigma=0}^\infty \binom{m}{\rho}\binom{n}{\sigma}x^{\rho+\sigma}.$$
Ok, so the coefficients of the two power series need be the same, that is
$$
\binom{m+n}{r}=\sum_{\rho+\sigma=r} \binom{m}{\rho}\binom{n}{\sigma}=\sum_{\sigma=0}^r \binom{m}{r-\sigma}\binom{n}{\sigma},$$
which is the Vandermonde identity. (To obtain the second sum from the first, we have used the change of variable $\rho=r-\sigma$).

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the binomial coefficients in
\begin{eqnarray*}
(1+x)^{m+n}&=&(1+x)^m(1+x)^n\\
[x^r]\left(\sum_{k=0}^{m+n} \color{red}{\binom{m+n}{k}} x^k\right)&=&[x^r]\left(\sum_{k=0}^{m} \color{red}{\binom{m}{k}} x^k\sum_{k=0}^{n} \color{red}{\binom{n}{k}} x^k\right) \\
\binom{m+n}{r}&=&[x^r]\left(\sum_{i=0}^{m} \binom{m}{i} x^i\right) 
 \left(\sum_{j=0}^{n} \binom{n}{j} x^j\right). \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I actually stuck from here. Sorry I forgot to put those coefficient in my body.

Answer (score 2):

The next step is to use convolution:
$$\left(\sum_{k\ge 0} a_k x^k\right)\left(\sum_{k\ge 0} b_k x^k\right)=\sum_{k\ge 0} c_k x^k,$$
where $c_k = \sum_{j=0}^k a_j b_{k-j}$.